# Thinkpad X1 Carbon wakes up from sleep automatically

Tags: 12.10, thinkpad, sleep

So, I bought a Thinkpad X1 Carbon and put Ubuntu Gnome Remix 12.10 on it. I've had an issue. Sometimes, the device will resume from its sleep state automatically. This has happened both under Windows and Ubuntu. All updates applied.

I have no idea what causes it, and the resume tends to happen some time (~1 hour) after:
a) I choose "Suspend" from the Gnome menu.
b) I unplug the machine from power.

This has occurred twice under Windows with Automatic updates disabled.
This has occurred at least 4 times on Ubuntu and I cannot recognize any pattern other than each time, I had a lot running. For example, stats show

RAM:
3.0GB (84.6%) of 3.6GB

SWAP:
3.8GB (47.5%) of 7.9GB

My theory is that after some time, it tries to hibernate (though it is disabled and I am unable to enable it in the menus). 'pm-hibernate' allows me to lose my work when I turn on my computre.

I have tried upgrading to Kernel 3.6.6 to see if any changes occurred, no change.

One peculiar note, the laptop itself blinks the 'moon light' while in sleep and documentation states that it will keep blinking as long as it is in SLEEP. This happens in Windows. In Linux, this stops after an hour or so, however, the system usually restores without issue from the sleep state.

I apologize for the long read. How can I troubleshoot and which logs are useful? 
I have made a copy of all in /var/log/.

Thanks you very much

Comment: Anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Bios, in the category "Power", there is a feature called

> Intel (R) Rapid Start Technology

Which tries to enter a more efficient sleep state after being asleep for (by default) an hour. You could try to disable this option.

Answer (score 1):

After two months of different experiments finally found the solution!

In my case: I put my X1 to sleep or hibernate and at some point, I find out the laptop has started by itself!

What has finally worked for me is:

1. Start Lenovo Vantage
2. Go to Hardware Settings
3. Go to Power
4. Turn OFF "Smart Standby"

That's it!!

Finally can put the laptop in the bag without worrying that it will start by itself while inside :-)