# Can I prevent my monitor from waking up my computer when I put my computer to sleep?

Tags: drivers, suspend, 23.10

So I have a bit of a strange issue ... when I put my laptop in a suspend state using the top-right menu in GNOME, it automatically turns on again after one second of sleep.

I unplugged all devices connected to my laptop one by one and found that my 4k Philips monitor is to blame. Without it, sleep works perfectly. When connected, the same faulty pattern appears again.

This is the output of **/proc/acpi/wakeup**:

```
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
GPP1      S4    *disabled
GPP2      S4    *disabled
GPP0      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:01.1
GPP5      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:02.1
GPP6      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:02.2
GPP7      S4    *disabled
GP11      S0    *disabled  pci:0000:00:03.1
SWUS      S4    *disabled
GP12      S0    *disabled
SWUS      S4    *disabled
XHC0      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:35:00.3
XHC1      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:35:00.4
XHC2      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:36:00.0
XHC3      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:36:00.3
XHC4      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:36:00.4
NHI0      S0    *enabled   pci:0000:36:00.5
NHI1      S0    *disabled
```

I went through the ones that are enabled but could not find any device of interest. Only a PCIe GPP Bridge and some USB Controllers.

Is there anything I can do to fix this problem? In theory, I have no problem preventing all peripherals from waking up the PC, because I always have access to the power button. However, if there is a way to disable the wakeup capability only for the HDMI device in `/sys/devices` I'm all ears.

Somewhat related:

- [Thinkpad X1 Carbon wakes up from sleep automatically](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217029/thinkpad-x1-carbon-wakes-up-from-sleep-automatically)
- [Immediate wake up from suspend caused by USB 3.0 devices](https://askubuntu.com/questions/545071/immediate-wake-up-from-suspend-caused-by-usb-3-0-devices)

Comment: Unfortunately, my monitor doesn't have such a button. It's a bit trash tbh

Comment: xset -display :0.0 dpms force off

Comment: I'm not trying to turn off the display. I'm trying to prevent it from wkaing up my computer from sleep.